# Firebase equalTo not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data in firebase looks as shown below.

```
items {
   item1: {
      field1: value1
      field2: value2
   }
   item2: {
      field1: value4
      field2: value3
   }
}
```

Now, I want to get all items where field2===value3. When I run the following query, I'm getting all items. Why?

```
firebase.database().ref().child('items')
        .orderByChild('field2')
        .equalTo('value3')
        .limitToLast(10)
        .once('value');
```

Comment: Are you using the Firebase version 3 API or the old version 2 API? The code doesn't look right. Where is the ref? With the version 3 API, it would be something like `firebase.database().ref().child(...`

Comment: I'm using the latest. In the code, firebase is my local variable which is qual to firebase.database().ref(). Let me change the question's code for better clarity

Comment: You say you get 'all items'. How many do you get? Can you include the received items in your question?

Comment: @cartant Sorry,ignore this. I was stupid. There was a parallel thread which was setting different result without filter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using queries, you can use `child_added` listener which will return all subitems in items and then you can perform the actions you want.

```
firebase.database().ref('items').on('child_added', snap => {
    if(snap.val().field2 == 'value3') {
        console.log('Match found in ' + snap.key); //Match found in item2
    }
});
```